# The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, dart, tensorflow-lite

I'm using :
Flutter : 2.5.3 (Stable)
Dart 2.14.4
Android Studio V2020.3.1 Patch 3

I was trying to download tflite and camera Packages and I got an error telling me to migrate the project to android embedding V2, So I did and then while trying to get these packages I faced the error mentioned in the title
thanks in advance

Comment: Error or warning? I have the same error with others plugins but its a warning and all execute correctly

Comment: Error I can't execute my code

Comment: just upgrade your dependency or degrade your flutter sdk

Comment: Include your error log in question so community can help